# Intercepting packets at openvswitch

Tags: controller, sdn, openflow, openvswitch

I'd like to intercept packets arriving at the switch from the controller (e.g. floodlight), and then do some processing for these packets. How can I go about that? Is there a good place I should start at?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

How about the snoop and monitor command documented [here](http://openvswitch.org/support/dist-docs/ovs-ofctl.8.txt)?

`snoop switch
 Connects  to switch and prints to the console all OpenFlow messages received.`

`monitor switch 
 Connects to switch and prints to the console all  OpenFlow  messages received.`

1. Write a script running snoop or monitor
2. Parse the output
3. "and then do some processing"

If you do not want with the OpenFlow messages but the packets, you can use [wireshark from the command line](https://www.wireshark.org/docs/wsug_html_chunked/ChCustCommandLine.html).